# What changed introduced C++20 enables us to omit the comparator argument in container's constructor?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

In C++17, the following code [fails to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/9efPh6jh3), and we need to provide an argument for `set`s constructor in order for it [to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/e9e7qTeY3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

int main() {
    auto comp = [](int l, int r) { return l > r; };

    // fails, needs comp as constructor argument
    auto set = std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(comp)>(); 
}
```

but in C++20 we can see that it [successfully compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/aG8jo8Wof).

What change in C++20 made this code work? I was looking at [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) and [its constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) but could not find any documented changes regarding to C++20.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708180/lambda-closure-type-constructors

Comment: Note on the duplicate closure: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63572081/10871073) to the first target seems to be an ideal answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C++20 lambdas like that (with no captures) are default-constructible. What's more, they can be used in unevaluated context:

```cpp
#include <queue>

int main() {
    auto set = std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype([](int l, int r) { return l > r; })>(); 
}
```